# How can I transpose a range with a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, vector, transpose

How can I transpose a range with a variable?

I am trying to turn a column vector into a row vector using Transpose, this is my code

```
    For i = 1 To nw
        If i = 1 Then
            Workbooks.Open FileNames(i)
            Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
          Title:="Number Format Rule From Cell", _
          Prompt:="Select a cell to pull in your number format rule", _
          Type:=8)
        End If

' here is where I'm having trouble

        transrng = range("A & i : A & (i + 4)")
        Importrng = rng.Address
        range(Importrng).Copy Destination:=tWB.Worksheets("Data").range("A" & i)
        Application.Transpose (transrng)

    Next i
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the interspersing of strings and variables below.

```
Set transrng = range("A" & i & ":A" & (i + 4))
```

Also:

```
    Importrng = rng.Address
    range(Importrng).Copy Destination:=tWB.Worksheets("Data").range("A" & i)
```

Is the same as

```
    rng.Copy Destination:=tWB.Worksheets("Data").range("A" & i)
```

Finally,

```
    Application.Transpose (transrng)
```

Should be

```
    Application.Transpose transrng
```

Those "()" have the effect of evaluating `transrng`, which will return the value (an array in this case), but you want Transpose to work on a Range.

Comment: transrng = range("A" & i & ":A" & (i + 4)) gives a Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed error message

Comment: @Toasted: Oops, I had forgotten to put the 'Set' in front of that line. Because `transrng` had not been assigned a value by that stage, the code that was originally there was trying to set an array of values (default property of a range) to nowhere! Post fixed.